# Python scraping of a site that contains PowerBI graphs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape the following URL in python:
https://msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,21995,420,873.html

What I need to get is the following:

If you open the Chrome developers tool while on the above URL and then go to the XHR section of the Network tab and look inside any "Name" column such as: "querydata?synchronous=true", in the "Request Headers" section there is a "Referer" URL. I need to obtain that URL from my python code so that I could decode its querystring and build my scraper.

This is how to navigate to the above URL:

From:

https://msdh.ms.gov/ (click on **Covid-19 Overview** link)

then from:

https://msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,0,420.html (click on **Interactive Map and Charts**)

and finally from:

https://msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,0,420,873.html (click on **Interactive Charts: COVID-19 Epidemiological Charts and Trends**)

Anyone has an idea how to get that Referer URL?

Comment: what's the usage of this referrer URL ?

Comment: The querystring is a base64 number that when decoded will contain a resource_key. The resource key is then used to build the header and payload for a subsequent POST to get the powerBI graph tooltip values. I could hardcode the querystring in my code, but the problem is that this not constant and it will change over time, and when it does it will break my code and I have to manually update the new value. What I want to accomplish is to dynamically get it from my python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was fun to figure out how to get info out of this site:

```
import re
import json
import base64
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,21995,420,873.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
html_data = requests.get(soup.iframe['src']).text

d = json.loads(base64.b64decode(soup.iframe['src'].split('=')[-1]).decode('utf-8'))

tenantId = d['t']
resourceKey = d['k']
resolvedClusterUri = re.search(r"var resolvedClusterUri = '(.*?)'", html_data)[1].replace('-redirect', '-api')
requestId = re.search(r"var requestId = '(.*?)'", html_data)[1]
activityId = re.search(r"var telemetrySessionId =  '(.*?)'", html_data)[1]

url = resolvedClusterUri + "/public/reports/" + resourceKey + "/modelsAndExploration?preferReadOnlySession=true"
query_url = resolvedClusterUri + "/public/reports/querydata?synchronous=true"
headers={'ActivityId': activityId, 'RequestId': requestId, 'X-PowerBI-ResourceKey': resourceKey}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for s in data['exploration']['sections']:
    if 'query' in s['visualContainers'][0]:

        payload = {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "queries": [
            {
              "Query": json.loads(s['visualContainers'][0]['query']),
              "CacheKey": '',
              "QueryId": "",
              "ApplicationContext": {
                "DatasetId": data['models'][0]['dbName'],
                "Sources": [
                  {
                    "ReportId": data['exploration']['report']['objectId']
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "cancelQueries": [],
          "modelId": data['models'][0]['id']
        }

        section_data = requests.post(query_url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()

        print(s['displayName'])
        print(section_data['results'][0]['result']['data']['dsr']['DS'][0]['PH'])
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Gender
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['Female', 12029]}, {'C': ['Male', 8469]}, {'C': ['Unknown', 143]}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cases and Deaths by Age
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M1', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['<18', 1480, 0]}, {'C': ['18-29', 3876, 5]}, {'C': ['30-39', 3272, 16]}, {'C': ['40-49', 3387, 40]}, {'C': ['50-59', 3106, 73]}, {'C': ['60-69', 2550, 199]}, {'C': ['70-79', 1555, 259]}, {'C': ['80-89', 993, 217]}, {'C': ['90+', 420, 129]}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pediatric
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['<1', 95]}, {'C': ['1-5', 299]}, {'C': ['6-10', 340]}, {'C': ['11-17', 746]}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hospitalized by Age Group
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['<18', 31]}, {'C': ['18-29', 114]}, {'C': ['30-39', 176]}, {'C': ['40-49', 328]}, {'C': ['50-59', 461]}, {'C': ['60-69', 635]}, {'C': ['70-79', 553]}, {'C': ['80-89', 332]}, {'C': ['90+', 137]}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hospitalized
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['No', 13849]}, {'C': ['Yes', 2767]}, {'C': ['Unknown', 1236]}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deaths by Race and Ethicity
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['Black (NH)', 463]}, {'C': ['White (NH)', 372]}, {'C': ['American Indian or Alaska Native (NH)', 35]}, {'C': ['Hispanic**', 15]}, {'C': ['Other (NH)', 1]}, {'C': ['Asian (NH)', 0]}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Underlying Condition
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M1', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M2', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M3', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M4', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M5', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['Hypertension', 311, 242, 21, 9, 1, 0]}, {'C': ['Cardiovascular Disease', 248, 197, 13, 6], 'R': 96}, {'C': ['Diabetes', 243, 129, 20, 3], 'R': 96}, {'C': ['Obesity', 168, 83, 9, 4, 0], 'R': 64}, {'C': ['Renal Disease', 129, 64, 13, 2], 'R': 96}, {'C': ['Lung Disease', 123, 108, 3, 1], 'R': 96}, {'C': ['Neurologic Conditions', 110, 143, 5, 2], 'R': 96}, {'C': ['Immunocompromised', 63, 49, 3, 1], 'R': 96}, {'C': ['Liver Disease', 14, 19, 2], 'R': 112}, {'C': ['None Noted', 2, 2, 0, 0, 1], 'R': 64}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Epi Curve
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 7}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M1', 'T': 3}], 'C': [1580515200000, 1], 'Ø': 4}, {'C': [1580688000000], 'R': 6}, {'C': [1581120000000], 'R': 6}, {'C': [1581379200000], 'R': 6}, {'C': [1581465600000], 'R': 6}, {'C': [1581638400000, 2], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1581811200000, 1], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1582156800000, '1.1428571428571428'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1582243200000], 'R': 6}, {'C': [1582416000000], 'R': 6}, {'C': [1582675200000, 2, '1.2857142857142858']}, {'C': [1582848000000, 3, '1.5714285714285714']}, {'C': [1582934400000, '1.7142857142857142'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1583020800000, 12, '3.2857142857142856']}, {'C': [1583107200000, 5, '3.8571428571428572']}, {'C': [1583280000000, '4.4285714285714288'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1583366400000, 1], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1583452800000, 12, '5.8571428571428568']}, {'C': [1583539200000, 8, '6.5714285714285712']}, {'C': [1583625600000, 11, '7.7142857142857144']}, {'C': [1583712000000, 35, 11]}, {'C': [1583798400000, 25, '13.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1583884800000, 23, '16.428571428571427']}, {'C': [1583971200000, 36, '21.428571428571427']}, {'C': [1584057600000, '24.857142857142858'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1584144000000, 40, '29.428571428571427']}, {'C': [1584230400000, 71, 38]}, {'C': [1584316800000, 94, '46.428571428571431']}, {'C': [1584403200000, 81, '54.428571428571431']}, {'C': [1584489600000, 112, '67.142857142857139']}, {'C': [1584576000000, 94, '75.428571428571431']}, {'C': [1584662400000, 123, '87.857142857142861']}, {'C': [1584748800000, 98, '96.142857142857139']}, {'C': [1584835200000, 92, '99.142857142857139']}, {'C': [1584921600000, 164, '109.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1585008000000, 137, '117.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1585094400000, 132, 120]}, {'C': [1585180800000, 119, '123.57142857142857']}, {'C': [1585267200000, 164, '129.42857142857142']}, {'C': [1585353600000, 101, '129.85714285714286']}, {'C': [1585440000000, 103, '131.42857142857142']}, {'C': [1585526400000, 162, '131.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1585612800000, 150, 133]}, {'C': [1585699200000, '135.57142857142858'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1585785600000, 149, '139.85714285714286']}, {'C': [1585872000000, 156, '138.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1585958400000, 143, '144.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1586044800000, 127, '148.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1586131200000, 206, '154.42857142857142']}, {'C': [1586217600000, 135, '152.28571428571428']}, {'C': [1586304000000, 178, '156.28571428571428']}, {'C': [1586390400000, 183, '161.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1586476800000, 178, '164.28571428571428']}, {'C': [1586563200000, 146, '164.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1586649600000, 141, '166.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1586736000000, 218, '168.42857142857142']}, {'C': [1586822400000, 214, '179.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1586908800000, 236, 188]}, {'C': [1586995200000, 191, '189.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1587081600000, 215, '194.42857142857142']}, {'C': [1587168000000, 171, 198]}, {'C': [1587254400000, 181, '203.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1587340800000, 307, '216.42857142857142']}, {'C': [1587427200000, 259, '222.85714285714286']}, {'C': [1587513600000, 280, '229.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1587600000000, 235, '235.42857142857142']}, {'C': [1587686400000, 276, '244.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1587772800000, 193, '247.28571428571428']}, {'C': [1587859200000, 170, '245.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1587945600000, 317, '247.14285714285714']}, {'C': [1588032000000, 278, '249.85714285714286']}, {'C': [1588118400000, 298, '252.42857142857142']}, {'C': [1588204800000, 245, '253.85714285714286']}, {'C': [1588291200000, 282, '254.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1588377600000, 193], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1588464000000, 148, '251.57142857142858']}, {'C': [1588550400000, 310, '250.57142857142858']}, {'C': [1588636800000, 290, '252.28571428571428']}, {'C': [1588723200000, 365, '261.85714285714283']}, {'C': [1588809600000, 274, 266]}, {'C': [1588896000000, 273, '264.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1588982400000, 168, '261.14285714285717']}, {'C': [1589068800000, 194, '267.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1589155200000, 356, '274.28571428571428']}, {'C': [1589241600000, 308, '276.85714285714283']}, {'C': [1589328000000, 274, '263.85714285714283']}, {'C': [1589414400000, 267, '262.85714285714283']}, {'C': [1589500800000, 332, '271.28571428571428']}, {'C': [1589587200000, 224, '279.28571428571428']}, {'C': [1589673600000, 172, '276.14285714285717']}, {'C': [1589760000000, 366, '277.57142857142856']}, {'C': [1589846400000, 302, '276.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1589932800000, 333, '285.14285714285717']}, {'C': [1590019200000, 355, '297.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1590105600000, 311, '294.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1590192000000, 236, '296.42857142857144']}, {'C': [1590278400000, 250, '307.57142857142856']}, {'C': [1590364800000, 291, '296.85714285714283']}, {'C': [1590451200000, 384, '308.57142857142856']}, {'C': [1590537600000, 383, '315.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1590624000000, 404, '322.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1590710400000, 306, 322]}, {'C': [1590796800000, 201, 317]}, {'C': [1590883200000, 179, '306.85714285714283']}, {'C': [1590969600000, 290, '306.71428571428572']}, {'C': [1591056000000, 256, '288.42857142857144']}, {'C': [1591142400000, 289], 'Ø': 4}, {'C': [1591228800000, 218], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591315200000, 260], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591401600000, 169], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591488000000, 120], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591574400000, 227], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591660800000, 222], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591747200000, 234], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591833600000, 263], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591920000000, 251], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1592006400000, 204], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1592092800000, 3], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1592179200000, 1], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1592265600000, 0], 'R': 4}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ethnicity/Race
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['Black (NH)', 9865]}, {'C': ['White (NH)', 5003]}, {'C': ['Hispanic**', 1134]}, {'C': ['American Indian or Alaska Native (NH)', 298]}, {'C': ['Other (NH)', 270]}, {'C': ['Asian (NH)', 58]}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deaths Gender x Race
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M1', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M2', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M3', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M4', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['Male', 247, 182, 8, 0, 23]}, {'C': ['Female', 229, 213, 4, 29], 'R': 16}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gender by Ethnicity/Race
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 1}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M1', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M2', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M3', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M4', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M5', 'T': 4}], 'C': ['Female', 6191, 2776, 494, 177, 141, 28]}, {'C': ['Male', 3641, 2209, 637, 121, 127, 30]}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LTCF
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'G0', 'T': 7}, {'N': 'M0', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M1', 'T': 4}, {'N': 'M2', 'T': 3}], 'C': [1584316800000, 0, 1], 'Ø': 8}, {'C': [1584576000000], 'R': 14}, {'C': [1584662400000], 'R': 14}, {'C': [1584748800000, 1, 2], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1585008000000, 0, 3], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1585094400000, 1], 'R': 10}, {'C': [1585180800000, 4], 'R': 10}, {'C': [1585267200000, 3, '2.2857142857142856'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1585353600000, 1, 5, 3]}, {'C': [1585440000000, 0, 3, '3.2857142857142856']}, {'C': [1585526400000, 7, '3.8571428571428572'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1585612800000, 2, 4, '4.2857142857142856']}, {'C': [1585699200000, 1, 12, 6]}, {'C': [1585785600000, 4, '6.1428571428571432'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1585872000000, 0, 7, '6.7142857142857144']}, {'C': [1585958400000, 3, 8, '7.4285714285714288']}, {'C': [1586044800000, 2, 7, '8.2857142857142865']}, {'C': [1586131200000, 1, 5, '8.1428571428571423']}, {'C': [1586217600000, 2, 8, '8.7142857142857135']}, {'C': [1586304000000, 6, 3, '8.1428571428571423']}, {'C': [1586390400000, 1, 8, '8.7142857142857135']}, {'C': [1586476800000, 3, 3, '8.5714285714285712']}, {'C': [1586563200000, 2, 6, '8.1428571428571423']}, {'C': [1586649600000, 3, 3, '7.7142857142857144']}, {'C': [1586736000000, 2, 6, 8]}, {'C': [1586822400000, 3, 9, '8.2857142857142865']}, {'C': [1586908800000, 4, 8], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1586995200000, 9, 9, '9.2857142857142865']}, {'C': [1587081600000, 5, 7, '10.142857142857142']}, {'C': [1587168000000, 4, 4], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1587254400000, 6, '10.714285714285714'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1587340800000, 8, 4, '11.285714285714286']}, {'C': [1587427200000, 6, 8, '11.571428571428571']}, {'C': [1587513600000, 0, 3, 11]}, {'C': [1587600000000, 8, 8, '10.714285714285714']}, {'C': [1587686400000, 6, 3, '10.285714285714286']}, {'C': [1587772800000, 3, 1, '9.7142857142857135']}, {'C': [1587859200000, 4, 3, '9.2857142857142865']}, {'C': [1587945600000, 12, 5, 10]}, {'C': [1588032000000, 7, 8, '10.142857142857142']}, {'C': [1588118400000, 8, 3, '11.285714285714286']}, {'C': [1588204800000, 9, '10.714285714285714'], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1588291200000, 7, '11.714285714285714'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1588377600000, 11, 8, '13.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1588464000000, 9, 4, '14.714285714285714']}, {'C': [1588550400000, 3, 6, '13.571428571428571']}, {'C': [1588636800000, 13, 9, '14.571428571428571']}, {'C': [1588723200000, 11, 2, '14.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1588809600000, 8, 1, '14.428571428571429']}, {'C': [1588896000000, 3, 7, '13.571428571428571']}, {'C': [1588982400000, 8, 2, '12.285714285714286']}, {'C': [1589068800000, 1, '11.714285714285714'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1589155200000, 6, 4, '11.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1589241600000, 9, 10, '11.428571428571429']}, {'C': [1589328000000, 11, 4, '11.714285714285714']}, {'C': [1589414400000, 12, 8, '13.285714285714286']}, {'C': [1589500800000, 13, 5, '14.428571428571429']}, {'C': [1589587200000, 9, 9, '15.571428571428571']}, {'C': [1589673600000, 14, 5, 17]}, {'C': [1589760000000, 5, 8, '17.428571428571427']}, {'C': [1589846400000, 12, 5, '17.142857142857142']}, {'C': [1589932800000, 8, 4, '16.714285714285715']}, {'C': [1590019200000, 7, 7, '15.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1590105600000, 6, '15.142857142857142'], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1590192000000, 8, 5, '14.428571428571429']}, {'C': [1590278400000, 11, 4, '13.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1590364800000, 8, 12, '14.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1590451200000, 10, 5, '14.571428571428571']}, {'C': [1590537600000, 8, 8, '15.142857142857142']}, {'C': [1590624000000, 7, 7], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1590710400000, 14, 9, '16.571428571428573']}, {'C': [1590796800000, 3, 4, '15.714285714285714']}, {'C': [1590883200000, 11, 2, '15.428571428571429']}, {'C': [1590969600000, 9, 7, '14.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1591056000000, 13, 4, '15.142857142857142']}, {'C': [1591142400000, 2, '13.714285714285714'], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591228800000, 9, 6, '13.857142857142858']}, {'C': [1591315200000, 2, '11.714285714285714'], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591401600000, 5, 2], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1591488000000, 6, 5, '11.428571428571429']}, {'C': [1591574400000, 5, '10.571428571428571'], 'R': 4}, {'C': [1591660800000, 4, '9.4285714285714288'], 'R': 2}, {'C': [1591747200000, 2], 'R': 4, 'Ø': 8}, {'C': [1591833600000, 1, 2], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1591920000000, 4, 6], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1592006400000, 5, 3], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1592092800000, 3, 5], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1592179200000, 2, 4], 'R': 8}, {'C': [1592265600000, 1, 0], 'R': 8}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Recovery
[{'DM0': [{'S': [{'N': 'M0', 'T': 3}], 'M0': 15323}]}]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That worked great and learned a great deal here. Thank you. I tried to do the same implementation on this URL: "https://www.doh.wa.gov/Emergencies/NovelCoronavirusOutbreak2020COVID19/DataDashboard", but it seems like it gets blocked by the server and does not return the html to parse. Do you know of a workaround. Could not find anything online.

Comment: @dmornad To not clutter this comment section, I suggest to open a new question.

Comment: I have a similar object from another website, but not clear to me how to build the table from this information @dmornad, any idea?

Comment: @davidvarenne did you ever figure this out? there's clearly some kind of compression scheme going on here where each row can inherit shared attributes from the previous row but it's still got me scratching my head. thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeD. In my application, I eventually figured out the delta compression. The key R is a bitfield representing which fields to re-use from the previous row. So in my case I have an R of 25, which corresponds to bits 1, 8 and 16. That means that for the first, fourth, and fifth fields, I just copy the previous row. You can think of R as "reuse."

Comment: There's also the "Ø" key, which seems to be another bitfield indicating missing data in a row. It's encoded in the same fashion.

Comment: Might come in handy: https://gist.github.com/svavassori/3319ff9d7e16a8788665ca59a5a04889