# How to create PowerBI payload queries info in python scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I used the technique outlined in the answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480695/python-scrapping-of-a-site-that-contains-powerbi-graphs) to apply it to the following URL:

https://www.michigan.gov/coronavirus/0,9753,7-406-98163_98173---,00.html

The request in that code only returns queries for the **"Current Status"** tab on the URL above and does not include any queries from other tabs such as **"Daily Cases"** which I need to build the payload for them.

I looked at all the requests in the browser developers tool and can not figure out where and how it gets those queries.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the page I see downloadable `.xlsx` data. Wouldn't be easier get the data that way?  (you can use `pandas` to open xlsx.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, thank you for your comment. Some of those excels such as Testing data do not provide all the components of data as we need whereas the graphs have them,ie, diagnostics and serology testing appear daily on the graph, but excel has only current day for serology.

Comment: @dmornad Did you end up figuring out how to get the other tabs? I'd really appreciate it if you could help out with that.

Comment: @KhalilHijazi, no I was not able to figure this out and I spent a lot of time on it.

Comment: @dmornad same here :( I also noticed that the results you get back are inconsistent. For instance, I could run one time and get back 20 sections, 13 of which have their payload queries, and then I could run a few days later and get back 20 sections, but this time with say 7 sections only that have payload queries. Not sure why that's happening though haha